# Shell script taking for argument a Python variable

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a simple Python script named 'scriptNastran.py' that calls a shell  through the subprocess function:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['sh', './launchNastran.sh'])
```

My launchNastran.sh is :

```
/appli/nastran -msc20121 TRAM mem=512M buffsize=25601 batch=no    
CHEMIN='/users/develop/tmp/input'
\cp -rf TRAM MODELE ./*f06 ./*f04 ./*log ./*op2 ./*pch $CHEMIN
```

The files TRAM and MODELE are in the same directory as the shell and the Python script. That directory is seen in the Shell: `CHEMIN='/users/develop/tmp/input`

However, the directory changes in the Python script, so I would like to pass the arg_directory defined in the Python script as an argument for the shell, something like:

```
import subprocess
arg_directory = 'hello world'
subprocess.call(['sh', './launchNastran.sh'])
```

For the python script and like this for the shell:

```
$ scriptNastran.py arg_directory

/appli/nastran -msc20121 TRAM mem=512M buffsize=25601 batch=no    
CHEMIN= arg_directory
\cp -rf TRAM MODELE ./*f06 ./*f04 ./*log ./*op2 ./*pch $CHEMIN
```

Does someone knows how to do it?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Your goal is run the `launchNastran.sh` within the python OR get the result from python then pass to  `launchNastran.sh` shell script ?

Comment: My goal is to run the launchNastran.sh within the python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the directory as an argument:

```
import subprocess
arg_directory = 'hello world'
subprocess.call(['sh', './launchNastran.sh', arg_directory])
```

and then read it in your shell script

```
/appli/nastran -msc20121 TRAM mem=512M buffsize=25601 batch=no    
CHEMIN="$1"
\cp -rf TRAM MODELE ./*f06 ./*f04 ./*log ./*op2 ./*pch "$CHEMIN"
```

Comment: Simple and elegant! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

`launchNastran.py`

```
def call_shell(CHEMIN_path):
    import subprocess
    ssh_command_string='''
        /appli/nastran -msc20121 TRAM mem=512M buffsize=25601 batch=no    
        CHEMIN={path}
        \cp -rf TRAM MODELE ./*f06 ./*f04 ./*log ./*op2 ./*pch $CHEMIN
    '''.format(path=CHEMIN_path). ## put the path you have in format 
    subprocess.Popen(ssh_command_string, shell=True)
call_shell('/users/develop/tmp/input') ## call the shell script
```